# Fourier Transform of $\ln(f(t))$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I want to compute Fourier transform of $\ln(f(t))$ maybe in a sense of distributions?
Where we can assume that:

1. $f(t) > 0$
2. $f(t) \in L^1$
3. $f(t)$ is continuous
4. $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t)=0$ and  $\lim_{t \to -\infty} f(t)=0$
5. Denote Fourier transform of $f(t)$ by $\mathcal{F}(f(t))=F(\omega)$

I am also fine with some other restrictions. For example: $f(t)$ is analytical (i.e. all derivatives exist)
My main question are:

1) is the above set of condition enough to guarantee existence of Fourier transform? If not, what are the requirements?

2)  what is the Fourier transform?

**Edit** Based on the suggestion of Mattos

\begin{align*}
&\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \ln(f(t)) e^{-i \omega t} dt=  \ln(f(t))\frac{e^{-j\omega t}}{-j\omega} \Big|_{t=-\infty}^{t=\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-j\omega t}}{-j\omega} \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)} dt\\
& =\ln(f(t))\frac{e^{-jwt}}{-jw} \Big|_{t=-\infty}^{t=\infty} +\frac{1}{j \omega}\mathcal{F} \left(\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)} \right)
\end{align*}

But, now how to compute $\ln(f(t))\frac{e^{-jwt}}{-jw} \Big|_{t=-\infty}^{t=\infty}$.

**Possible Solution to 2):**

I might have solution but not sure. It relays on using the following property.

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F} \left( \frac{d}{dt} g(t) \right)=(j\omega) \mathcal{F}(g(t))
\end{align*}

Now take $g(t)=\ln(f(t))$ so we have
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F} \left( \frac{d}{dt} \ln(f(t)) \right)=(j\omega) \mathcal{F}(\ln(f(t)))\\
\mathcal{F} \left(  \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\right)=(j\omega) \mathcal{F}(\ln(f(t)))\\
\frac{\mathcal{F} \left(  \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\right)}{(j\omega)}= \mathcal{F}(\ln(f(t)))
\end{align*}

So, of course this solution requires that $f'(t)$ exists. 
Is this reasoning correct? Is there any technicality that I missed?

**Here is the example I tried**

Let $f(t)=e^{-t^2}$ then $\ln(f(t))=-t^2$, 
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}(\ln(f(t)))=\mathcal{F}(-t^2)=2\pi\delta^{(2)}(\omega)
\end{align*}

On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{j \omega} \mathcal{F} \left( \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)} \right)&=\frac{1}{j \omega} \mathcal{F} \left( \frac{-2te^{-t^2}}{e^{-t^2}} \right)=\frac{1}{j \omega} \mathcal{F} \left( -2t \right)=-2 \frac{1}{j \omega} (2 \pi j) \delta^{(1)}(\omega)\\
&=  -(4 \pi ) \frac{1}{ \omega}\delta^{(1)}(\omega)=(2 \pi ) \delta^{(2)}(\omega)
\end{align*}

the last equality uses $\omega \delta^{(2)}(\omega)=-2\delta^{(1)}(\omega)$

So, this is an example when my approach works.

Thank you for any help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships. Check number 317, it gives the case for $f(t) = \lvert t \rvert$. Alternatively, you could try integrating by parts, setting $u = ln(f(t))$, $dv = e^{-i\omega t}$. Or you could use residues. Here is something on using the Laplace transform https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/laplace-transform.95184/.

Comment: Is there some sort of symmetry you could exploit to change the limits in the integral to something more manageable?

Comment: I guess we can add an assume that $f(t)$ is symmetric around $t=0$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: That can't work, because $\ln(f)$ is not integrable. You have proved that $\ln(f) \leq f$, but to prove integrability you need a bound on $|ln(f)|$. And here, since $f$ vanishes at infinity, $\ln(f)$ goes to $-\infty$ at infinity, so is not integrable at all. It has no reason to be a tempered distribution either. Hence, the Fourier transform of $\ln(f)$ has no reason to be well-defined.

Comment: Yes, you are right about my integrability argument I will remove it. Can we find a necessary condition for existence of this Fourier transform?

Comment: Or rather sufficient

Comment: If $\lim\limits_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=0$, then $\lim\limits_{|x|\to\infty}\log(f(x))=-\infty$. $\log(f(x))$ does not look as if it has a Fourier Transform.

Comment: @robjohn What about in terms of temperate distributions? For example $x^2$ doesn't have a Fourier transform in a classical sense but it does have one if use method of distributions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For suitable $f$, we have
$$
\mathcal{F}(f')(\xi)=2\pi i\xi\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)
$$
Therefore, if one exists, it would be
$$
\mathcal{F}(f'/f)(\xi)=2\pi i\xi\mathcal{F}(\log(f))(\xi)
$$
which would lead to
$$
\mathcal{F}(\log(f))(\xi)=\frac1{2\pi i\xi}\mathcal{F}(f'/f)(\xi)
$$
if $f'/f$ has a Fourier Transform.

---

To show a bit more care, we can make the preceding a bit more rigorous, by letting $\phi(x)=e^{-\lambda x^2}$ and sending $\lambda\to0^+$:
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^\infty\log(f(x))\phi(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1{2\pi i\xi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\phi(x)+\log(f(x))\phi'(x)\right)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\to\frac1{2\pi i\xi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Let me restate. if $f'/f$ has a Fourier transform then $\mathcal{F}(\log(f))=\frac{1}{2\pi \omega}  \mathcal{F}(f'/f)$, right?

Comment: could you also use $e^{-\lambda|t|}$ as a test function?

Comment: @tired: that should work since it's derivative does not have any mass at $0$.

Comment: @tired see my example to see when this approach works. The only think I need now is the sufficient condition for existence of this Fourier transform

Comment: hmm i get a term proportinal to $\delta(\omega)\log(f(0))$ but maybe i'm just to superficial in making the correct limiting procedure.

Comment: it seems to work out if i apply the limit $\lambda->0$ directly after partial integration, but not if i'm using diracs identity which is somehow strange.

Answer (score 3):

To supplement the answer already given, i will use the trick of adding a small real part to the exponent $i\omega t \rightarrow i\omega t-\delta|t|$ so that the integral is convergent for large $t$. 
We then have to calculate the following expression:
$$
\lim_{\delta\rightarrow0}\int_0^{\infty}e^{i\omega t-\delta t}\log (g(t))+\lim_{\delta\rightarrow0}\int_{-\infty}^0e^{i\omega t+\delta t}\log (g(t))
$$

Partial integration yields 
$$
\lim_{\delta\rightarrow0}\big{(}\underbrace{\frac{1}{i\omega-\delta}[e^{i\omega t-\delta t}\log (g(t))]_0^{\infty}}_{(1)}-\underbrace{\frac{1}{i\omega-\delta}\int_0^{\infty}e^{i\omega t-\delta t}\frac{g'(t)}{g(t)}}_{(2)}+\\
\underbrace{\frac{1}{i\omega+\delta}[e^{i\omega t+\delta t}\log (g(t))]_{-\infty}^0}_{(3)}-\underbrace{\frac{1}{i\omega+\delta}\int_{-\infty}^0e^{i\omega t+\delta t}\frac{g'(t)}{g(t)}}_{(4)}\big{)}
$$

Now assuming that the FT of $(g'/g)$ exists, we can perform the limit after plugging in the endpoints of the integration domain.

We see that $(1)+(3)=0$ and $(2)+(4)=$

$$ 
\frac{-1}{i\omega}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\omega t}\frac{g'(t)}{g(t)}=\frac{-1}{i\omega}\text{FT}\big{[}\frac{g'(t)}{g(t)}\big{]}
$$ 
which is the same as in robs answer, by identifying $i\omega \rightarrow -2 \pi i \xi$

Please note that this crucially depends on the order in which we take limit and integration. For some reason this seems not to work out if we want to interpret this FT in the sense of distributions by applying Dirac's identity, which is at least surprising to me because i think this is the more general way to look at it.